# Highcharts - Bubble graph : need bubble to overflow plot area

Tags: highcharts

I need to keep my chart under specific X and Y axis delimitation but I also need to allow overflow of my bubbles in my bubble chart. I noticed that hovering the bubble make it overflow, isn't it possible to force it permanently in some ways?

Comment: [Here is my jsfiddle for example](http://jsfiddle.net/lestote/bp54a36z/)

Comment: You could disable halo on hover state, so it wont overflow plot area - http://jsfiddle.net/bp54a36z/15/

Comment: Thanks for the reply but im precisely looking on the opposite : i need the bubble to overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no default option to set minimum range without setting min or max. It is possible to set min/max to axes is chart's callback when default axis extremes are not small (min) or big (max) enough, but for bubble chart it might cause bubble to be partially cut (not fully visible).

You could add hidden scatter series that will hold min/max by its points, so if bubbles are on the edge chart will adjust itself to fit them.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bp54a36z/16/

```
{
     type: 'scatter',
     showInLegend: false,
     enableMouseTracking: false,
     dataLabels: {
         enabled: false
     },
     data: [[0.1,40],[10,-40]],
     marker: {
         enabled: false
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much your answer allowed me to get where i needed. Thanks for the follow up!